# How do you send call to main class from a class file?

Tags: java, class

Hi I have 1 main program file 2 class files involved in this. In the main class file I create a frame and control how they interact. One of my class files needs to talk back to the main class file to change the 3rd file. I am trying go find out how that call would be sent back.

The Main class file:

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public MainFrame() {
    buttonPanel1 = new ButtonPanel();
    textPanel1 = new TextPanel();
    textPanel2 = new TextPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(buttonPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(textPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(textPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(buttonPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(textPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(textPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );
    pack();
}                     

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
    });
}

public void copyText() {
    textPanel2.setText(textPanel1.getText());
}

private ButtonPanel buttonPanel1;
private TextPanel textPanel1;
private TextPanel textPanel2;
```

}

The button class file that tries to call back to the main file. to change the 3rd file.

```
public class ButtonPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    public ButtonPanel() {
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton1.setText("Change");
        jButton1.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> {


//I would like to tell Main Frame to get TextPanel1 and put into TextPanel2
        MainFrame.copyText();

         });

       javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(jButton1))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(jButton1))
        );
    }                                                          
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;             
}
```

and the one being changed:

```
public class TextPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
public TextPanel() {
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField1.setText("Hello");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 59, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );
    }                    

    public String getText(){
        return jTextField1.getText();
    }
    public void setText(String str){
        jTextField1.setText(str);
    }                   
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the method static, this will work, but you won't be able to directly access the object.

```
MainFrame.copyText();
```

Otherwise, just pass a reference to mainFrame to the ButtonPanel. For example:

```
public ButtonPanel(MainFrame mainFrame) {
    this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
...
}
```

And create like this on mainframe:

```
new ButtonPanel(this);
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing this but it looks like it will be the only way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MVC (Model-View-Controller) paradigm to separate things, and keep some overview.

One **Controller** regulates everything: it keeps the data **Model** and GUI **View**. Events, changes to the model are passed to the controller, and that then calles methods on the views.

The Controller class (like `Application`) has just one instance and would be some general purpose class with methods like `Application.get().copyText()` and holding the View (`MainFrame`) and Model (data, String).

```
public class Application { // The controller
    private static final Application instance = new Application();
    private MainFrame frame;

    public static Application get() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
```

In Application.copyText then probably a MainFrame method is called. A bit of ping-pong. But keeping the business logic (control flow) outside the verbose GUI code.

Other techniques are to have separate Action classes for buttons, extending AbstractAction.